# tar ignoring "newer" option

Tags: centos, tar

How do I get tar to only include files newer than a certain date? I have tried the following, both of which include older and newer files (today is 2015-07-20):

- `tar -cj -N 2015-07-07 directory | tar -tj | less`
- `tar -cj -N 2015-07-25 directory | tar -tj | less`
- <strike>`tar -cj --newer-mtime=2015-07-25 directory | tar -tj | less`</strike>

Comment: `tar -cj --newer-mtime=2015-07-25 directory | tar -tj | less` works for me.
`tar --version` ?

Answer (score 1):

`tar -cj --newer-mtime 2015-07-07 directory | tar -tj | less` works

If `-N` is used, `tar` works on files whose data modification or status change times are newer than the `date` given.

While `--newer-mtime` only checks `mtime` and disregards `ctime`